Why does permission alerts inside a NavigationStack clear the navigationPath?
I ran into an weird bug this afternoon and I have no clue about what's happening.

The problem is, as soon as the permission alert is shown, the navigation goes back to the root of the navigation stack. And this problem only exists using simulators, it works perfectly fine on a real device.
Here is the code I used :
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView(selection: .constant(0)) {
                NavigationSplitView(columnVisibility: .constant(.all)) {
                    Form {
                        Text("")
                            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: .constant(true)) {
                                ContentView()
                            }
                    }
                } detail: {
                    Text("detail")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var navigationPath: NavigationPath = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
            NavigationLink(value: "Toto") {
                Text("Toto")
            }.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { agentDay in
                Button {
                    AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { _ in
                        
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text("Ask Permission")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

My App is more complex but this is the exact hierarchy that caused the problem (It had a lot of VStack, HStack & stuff that wasn't relevant).
If you move the NavigationPath to TestApp, the bug disappear. If you remove any of the component of the view hierarchy, the bug disappear too. Any of these 2 options isn't really good to me, unless I understand what's the problem in this code ... I'm afraid that if I don't solve it, it will break other things later
Anyone has an idea about what's happening ? I'm completly lost ...

constant bindings are just for previews

It’s just to simplify the code when analyzing the bug, if you use a state property as a binding it doesn’t change anything
